# Continuous mapping onto itself s.t. $f(A) = A$ where $A$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separable-spaces

> Let $f$ be a continuous mapping of a Hausdorff non-separable space $(X,\tau)$ onto itself. Prove that there exists a proper non-empty closed subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f(A) = A$.
>
> [ Hint: Let $x_0 \in X$ and define a set $S = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ such that $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ for every integer n ]
>
> Is the above result true if $(X,\tau)$ is separable? (Justify your answer.)

I can find some examples of such maps and closed sets.

Let $f$ be a continuous function:

$$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x) = -x$$

and let set $A = \{-1, 1\}$. Then $A$ is closed, proper and non-empty and $f(A) = A$.

I need some help with general proof. If at some stage $f(x_n) = x_0$ then sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ is finite and closed. Otherwise it's infinite countable. Can't guess how to use non-separability here ...

Comment: With $f(x)=-x$ consider the set consisting of the single point $0$.

Comment: Consider the set containing two points and let $f$ exchange them.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=\overline{\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$. Since $X$ is non-separable, $A\neq X$. On the other hand, $A$ is closed and $f(A)=A$.

On the other hand, if $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z|=1\}$ and $f\colon S^1\longrightarrow S^1$ is defined by $f(z)=e^{i\theta}z$, where $\theta\in\mathbb R$ is such that $\frac\theta\pi\notin\mathbb Q$, then there is no such $A$.

Comment: How is it assured that $x_0\in f(A)$?

Comment: @drhab The definition in the question has $\mathbb Z$ rather than $\mathbb N$ - $f$ is onto.

Comment: $ f[A] \subseteq A $ follows from the continuity of $ f $ and the fact that $ f[S] = S $. Why is the converse true?

Comment: @drhab Such a sequence can be found because the problem stated that $ f $ was onto. Thus, for $ n \in \mathbb Z $, $f^{-1}[{x_n}] \neq \emptyset $, so let $ x_{n-1} $ be something in that preimage.

Comment: @user571438 Thank you. I overlooked "onto".

Comment: @drhab I suppose that the $\mathbb{Z}$ in the hint was meant to be $\mathbb{Z}^+,$.

Comment: @MarkBennet You re right, of course. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @josé-carlos-santos, is my understanding correct? - we can pick any $x_0$ and build a sequence both directions: $x_1 = f(x_0)$ and $x_{-1} \in f^{-1}(x_0)$, therefore we can build a sequence for $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Andreo In the case of the function that I mentioned, yes, since it has an inverse.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, what argument do you use to show that $f(A) = A$ ?

Comment: In this case, $A=S^1$ and $f$ is a bijection from $S^1$ onto $S^1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, how about general case? Given that $f(S) = S$ and all other assumptions, prove that $f(\overline{S}) = \overline{S}$ ...

Answer (score 1):

You can choose as $A=cl(S)$ and in this case your set is closed and proper (and oviously non-empty) because if $cl(S)=A=X$ than X is separable ($S$ is a countable set) and so $A\neq X$

Now we prove that $f(A)=A$:

$f(S)=S$ and so $ f(A)=f(cl(S))\subset cl(f(S))=cl(S)=A$ and for the other side you can use the property $T_2$

Comment: Don't you need the space to be first countable to get such a sequence?

Comment: @user571438 why do you think the space should be first countable?

Comment: The answer was edited so my comment no longer applies. Previously, it used the fact that $ x \in \overline{S} $ implies that there is a sequence in $ S $ converging to $ x $, which I believe needs first countability to do.

Comment: Sure sorry , I was  wrong and so I changed the proof

Comment: @user571438 could you give a hint hot to use Hausdorffness to prove: $A \subseteq f(A)$ ?

Comment: I have no idea and I ‘m thinking that could be false