# Is Axiom of choice required to define $S = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where $x_n=f^n(x_0)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Suppose that $X$ is a set and $f$ a map defined from $X$ **onto** $X$. Is the axiom of choice required to define

$$S = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

where $x_0 \in X$ is given and $x_n = f^n(x_0)$?

If not what is a definition of $S$ in $ZF$?

The origin of my question is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829157/continuous-mapping-onto-itself-s-t-fa-a-where-a-is-closed).

Comment: $f^{-1}(x_0)$ is not defined a priori so what is $x_{-1}$ ?

Comment: As $f$ is supposed to be onto, the inverse image under $f$ of $x_0$ is not empty. $x_{-1}$ is one of those preimage.

Comment: There is a good idea behind this post, but it is phrased essentially as just a problem statement. Posts of that form are discouraged - could you edit the post to include more context?

Comment: @CarlMummert I edited the question to provide the origin of my question. Not sure however that it will provides a much deeper background as the original question is disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining $ S' = \{x_n \, : \, n\geq 0\} $ does not need any choice. However, your instincts are correct that defining the sequence for negative values of $ n $ uses a form of choice, as there is no specific element in the fiber $ f^{-1}[x_n] $ to select. However, you do not need the full axiom of choice. Indeed, you can use the [axiom of dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) to define this set.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but I don't understand "as there is no specific element in the fiber $f^{-1}[x_n]$ to select." If we were given (by some set-theoretic definition) a specific element to select, for each $n$, then we wouldn't need any form of choice.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I meant to place that statement earlier, and I'll edit the post to fix this. Your statement is absolutely correct, if we already had such an element per $ n $ then any form of choice would be superfluous. However, my intention in mentioning that was to emphasize that choice is necessary in this problem.

Comment: Consider A={$x_{-1},x_{-2},.....$}, a countable family of sets, not necessarily disjoint.The existence of a choice function (Munkres &9, P57) allows to pick an element from each set,ok.Since A is countable do we need to invoke the existence of a choice function, or can we pick an element from each set $x_{-k}$ ?Thanks.

Comment: You do need to invoke some form of choice, but you don't need the full axiom of choice. Countable sets are still infinite, so you can't justify taking an element feom every set purely from ZF. If it was finite then sure, you can just use induction, but you can't induct to infinity so you need a new method when dealing with any sort of infinite choice.